# BeautifulSoup HTML extracting tabular data; loop <tr> <th> <td>

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

This is an example of a HTML table I need to extract data from. The table is
repetative with a < tr>, < th> and < td>

```
<table class="tablename">
<tr>
    <th> Animal </th>
    <td> Dog </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th> Fish </th>
    <td> Salmon </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th> Colour </th>
    <td> Red </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

My code is something like this:

```
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(readHtml, 'html.parser')
tableClassResults = soup.find("table", { "class" : "tablename" })

tr = tableClassResults.find('tr')
th = tr.find('th')
print "th = ", th
td = tr.find('td')
print "td = ", td
```

This is working fine for the first < tr>, giving th = Animal and td = Dog. My problem is that I want to loop through all of the < tr> and extract the < td> and the corresponding < td>. I've found some similar questions, but I cannot figure out how to do the findNext and loop part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`find_all`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all) to get all matched elements.

Then iterate over the return value of the method to iterate `th`, `td` below the `tr` elements:

```
for tr in tableClassResults.find_all('tr'):
    th = tr.find('th')
    print "th = ", th
    td = tr.find('td')
    print "td = ", td
```

---

Output for the given HTML:

```
th =  <th> Animal </th>
td =  <td> Dog </td>
th =  <th> Fish </th>
td =  <td> Salmon </td>
th =  <th> Colour </th>
td =  <td> Red </td>
```